# If you learn the 2000 most common kanji, how many of the 2000 most common hanzi would you know?

Tags: kanji, chinese

For someone interested in learning both Japanese and Mandarin, how much overlap is there? How many more characters would you have to learn to know the 2000 most common hanzi?

Comment: I don't see how this question is primarily opinion-based.  It's hard to believe that no one's ever compiled a frequency list for hanzi, and there are certainly lots of frequency lists people have made for kanji, so it seems like it should be objectively answerable.

Comment: As other posters have noted, sometimes there's been significant semantic drift -- if not in the meanings of individual characters, then in the meanings of the compounds.  My favorite example: JA 手紙: _tegami_, "hand" + "paper" = "a letter, an epistle (writing that you post to someone)", vs. Mandarin ZH 手紙 _shǒuzhǐ_, "hand + "paper" = "toilet paper".  So be careful what you send via post!  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Using 2,136 as a reference number (total number of Jōyō kanji)*

There are 3,079 unique* characters which form the 2,136 most frequent Mainland Chinese + Taiwan Chinese characters.

- 1567 Jōyō Kanji are part of these 3,079 characters, while 569 are not*:

  - 1113 characters of the 2,136 most frequent Mainland Chinese characters are also part of the Jōyō kanji
  - 1395 characters of the 2,136 most frequent Taiwan Chinese characters are also part of the Jōyō kanji

---

Data mined from:

- Taiwan Chinese: [字頻總表](https://sites.google.com/site/tmdshare/home/99nian-xia-jiao-xue-gong-zuo-fang-zhi-biao-zu-zi-liao/zi-pin-biao/%E5%AD%97%E9%A0%BB%E7%B8%BD%E8%A1%A8.txt?attredirects=0&d=1) (ultimately from 教育部語文成果網, language.moe.gov.tw)
- Mainland Chinese: [汉字单字字频总表](http://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/list.php?Which=TO)

---

**Not part of* or *unique* here means that they are mapped to different Unicode codepoints. This means that

- Some minor variations, such as Simplified Chinese radical differences (証 vs. 证) are counted as different characters;
- Some minor variations, such as the [Shinjitai-unique characters that are mapped identically onto Traditional Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai#J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_Kanji), are counted as the same character.

<sub>*For reference the characters you'll have to learn to recognise the most frequent.*</sub>


<sub>**Mainland Chinese** (1023 characters)  
怀挂辅耀涉谈伊戌亏渔窗尘娜废贞欢两斩吨伪训爬纯键拿临尸邻场宽线贾见础词牌经济姑牢乔狗奖员坚话统赞卢查龄揭扬恰韵其闹摸设绿阔邀调厂庄娇馆针验昏脑吓懂应错确灵鸟肠订摇兰枪抬碰讲朵爷盈费咸逻之阿允检释组视哈恶鹏插录仔祸浙拜也惠董询产剧秦浩填迪淮菲维穷谨须灾狼广梁码冀沉箭渊频餐划朔盘蒙帅军业劝猜辟搞姚亥伤质个铜顷纵缴获耶粹贸离饶笼吾胁荡跃剂仅寇哉效苍柏郑绕诗晚卜迟瑞胡强馀哩徽详竭饰巳亿请顶击智矿态禀节阅构领稍厌树趋帕寅庚伟撞堡责抢严织梦吩涨纪术粮冰劲渐找尹躺讼净嫂际俄歇此汉奋囊坏姐浓勒陕胖滚孙桌几拢卧烦门绪扭软电柴卷试养导齿宁稀溃溪颇匆辉师而鼎库尔颗龙抛炮怜沟霞计罚尤碧辩劫贪骂莱舰纳躲竟弯边阵贺值证练摄荆么勋啊种职李发结换卖这湘绣汤烧韩晨敦凭祀轮诱扰绳迹癸恼标历语宋喊复谏马专萨优伙冤创饮颜鸣败缩别悬启阳冲贵样弹纸姆炼达晃观泄假识终奶屏筑狐晓萧敕魏遗绘胜瑟连卡狠另佩扫闪饭壬赵仿偷叶晕驻腾兽嘴锁较适罗妇舆圈压吊碍吃疏骑瘦输递崔或庙弘玛帮额丞务逢唤莫袭斯谕焉澳诸贴纹霸玻举污埃桂资穆伍藏乎荐赔诺给潘诛跟矣恢哥绩轨毫汪热谓狱跨寻显亚简弃仪谅备嘉辈耍册于缺缓层吕卯抖阙农负庞宠圣营辨茫贯亮舱记队夷为俩难扁锡权烂捷义迈桥糊缘凌赏黎剑鲁套拖仍还监慧坐险卫哪灭驱呵轿您曾铺长图肃异厅醉售蒋昌芬传邓熙倘岛东做级锦猪舍测厉莲贤纷收钻挺辽势旁呀杂毅户仇你觉默乌苏跑归毕仗赖泛违总拟罢该继啦兮旱赶鸿价杨忽勿气洁碗脉谋编霍戏睛咐积刘题缝甫蔡挥护丧杰储币宪纲撰钟艰夹炸论妾审狄乘酉诊浑桓单虏飘诚读步豫只彭们扯掩访车陷时兹类艾载综穿拔岁销跪昂悉愈斋戊宏怎锐岂笔尖墙薛刚殷报挤瞧谦截讯泪钱决鉴德很脸县倾铁过摆雍每赐宫疯游凉扩骗绝杜赠拥执忧惩园转误逼奸闻艺份顾谁毁暂舅选妈锋碎叛众洛抚丝增红认徙钦贫贡邮亲陈孟办丽围评掠览赋协风她块衙谥赛远损飞屡译团货镜姨赫亦仓药曼关牵说臂银项虽卿极袁圆掉戈靖猎辑帐抓无艘战些搜爱财现伦让听梯丰劳洲况烟爸夺琼肿迁习诉蛋腊华乐燕联杖托楚惟邑赢彦坦闭惯於俱买敲愿闲叹鱼签涂悄弗辆按隐吗辖续丛间贝鲜实纠肤吧驰动丫细购咬议开稳吞宾什汇忆晋姊网对丢问从瓜坡扑扣饥侧韦孩拨偿曰已筹盐顿课蜀它傅处润舒鞋逊鲍吴戎云环疗乃坛预张谢愤带播唬冯估头喷阶犹债贼杀岭襄陆聊响敌减扎黑齐驶站补进聚蓝鼠满靠诣呢煤书择聪哭凯轰兴闷并顺泽驾阁郁范蒂禄庆朋涌脏咱丑络撒怕则肚尝嘛够阴鸡侠欣钢篇紧约讨呆辰贷隶爹许疼儿巴规镇仆绍惊跌虑运擒恕诏盖变佛汝轻竞乡翠荣遥凤剩寨侦翰页腿雕彻雾饿</sub>


<sub>**Taiwan Chinese** (741 characters)  
耀謂脆涉專伊纏憑貓窗趙錢礦薩厭爬睜徵渴銷傻缺裡翅藉豈齊牌黏姑詢狗廟敞賣查蹤腦揭凱聰鳳歲變其鷹摸滿邀吃噪與雀鴉乃昏臂輕柯丟氣蠶芬單碰琳厲朵嚴誼阿籃闊姆哈嗎插罕仔驗拜也惠董叢秦浩迪惡菲譽拼梁閃樂沉箭劍嬌餐經舒輔蒙售猜吞夠麥倦歡鴨醫芭傳辯嘴鄰戲麵耶媽吾靈齡篇恆效釋柏號雕佔敘駛晚濟瑞胡緣牢繪譬俯惱佩蝴數智幫膀稍們憐顯矮撞堡膠蔣檢澤鬧趨脫險爭輯應悶躺殼擴觀俄歇囊擎灑姐勒處靜胖汙淘廚跨盪扭寬蓮柴捷牽彿擾戀溪萄鬆贊而爐趕碗挖肅霞釘尤碧冰劫戰褲涵錶游覽值撿眾黃吊蹈啊槍灌彎兒豔乘牠廣藥晨敦燭廳蟹櫻喊碌頗莖伙爛從縣慧恰隨鄭甜稻嶺碼狀晃懂假轉盈奶屏鞭燒絕擔默淚瑟卡另罩黨橫發鋒賴偷寶淺玫垃甄圈宋萊袍疏劑薯或團條謠逢撥攤莫斯歸嬰澳戶霸玻渾勁區埃桂牆曉佈藏乎歐糕缸蛙裝跟繞恢哥毫瑪聲懷淨壽畫讀會嘉很贏圓炒魯抖榜亞鄧誦辨茫亮稱吵彈迴卷拆擊凌黎套拖據啟點內坐繩哪艱巴腔卻擺聽懼滾稀醉權龍昌抬雙榮做於撫匆辭吳陌閱碳漲營收頸挺夾旁呀毅你臉擋鍊癌跑豐壓齒灘泛竟煞啦溼瑰寵當忽繼拿慾汪窄蘇鄉莊圍續睛撐檔嘗礙氛讚溜妞鬥您妮遲脹炸麼獅闆珊寫雜孕體學盜啡擠灣步虧兩賽只蟲獵陷她找曼穿拔攀昂錄悉愈訊宏怎紐妓搖餘截實馳儲蹟德搶喻爺朋邊鐵呆棉淋仍每晒樸慘杜遞此膽剪逼蕩撒勵價圾份捐餃亂稅碎霍咖這洛增綠脣暢馨說蘭匯炮躲鴻總廂驅燈桌盒驕遙臘李孟壞葡廢姨赫鋪譯腳彷駕邁劃掉徑抓圖掙些搜碟產猴掩溫萬梯銳洲爸舊擇蛋楊籌烏獎燕箏托楚藝畢臥坦豬壯疼俱敲蝶娃悄將來按瘋尖屬樓閒儘匙嘛攝樣夥吧辦歷咬禮絲餵覺蒼什糊飄證之姊顏潑祕虛鵝瓜寞坡廠扣烤孩繫聯叮曰已勸伍臺桿它悅蘆劉鞋讓芙轎潛鼠觸瘦窩播蔬關隱估污斷帶雞爾址參疊聊仿扎黑罐寓兔站聚臟盡靠呢奧獨哭扮剩棵巷狹獸蟻峽艾蒂舉國墊對沒怕紗纖殘輛肚綜欣亦顆縱簽嶼曆屍跌雖佛磚獻勞繡翠賺攜氧穩髮塵菸舍曾鑽腿</sub>

Comment: For reference: [these](https://pastebin.com/7JhyAuBP) are the Mainland Chinese characters and [these](https://pastebin.com/rGHLMWab) are the Taiwan Chinese characters that you'll have to learn to recognise the 2,136 most frequent.

Comment: I added the characters from your comment to the body of the answer (in `<sub>` tags). This way the information will not suffer from link rot. You can delete it again from your answer if you prefer, in which case the characters will stay as part of the edit history.

Answer (score 3):

The total number of Jōyō kanji in Japan is 2136.

6335 kanji was used in publications in China, according to research in 1975 and 1976, and 2400 kanji accounted for 99％ of them. So we should think the total number of Jōyō kanji in China is 2400.

Jōyō kanji in Japan same as in China is 1600, so the answer for your question is 1600. However some of them have different meaning and readings, so you may be confused with them.

Source: http://agora-web.jp/archives/2023959-2.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a partial issue with the implications from your question, which namely come from recognition of characters versus pronunciation, and from meaning. There are plenty of kanji that have flat out different readings and meanings from the equivalently written hanzi, meaning you would simply be able to recognize those characters as symbols present also in Japanese. Sorry to be a spoil sport.

Comment: I am aware of that. I did not mean how many characters would you know the meaning of, only how many you would recognize.